# Prevent XSS attacks

Tags: php, xss

Is this code secure to prevent XSS attacks  ??

```
<?php
   $string = "<b>hello world!</b>";
   echo "without filtering:".$string;
   echo "<br>";
   $filtered = htmlspecialchars($string); // insert into database filtered
   echo "After filtering:".$filtered;
   echo "<br>";
   $de_filtering = htmlspecialchars_decode($filtered); //retrieve from database and display
   echo "After de-filtering:".$de_filtering;        
  ?>
```

Comment: It's a start in the right direction. You need to show more code, a real world example from your app. This alone is just theory.

Comment: If you're putting data into a database, don't use `htmlspecialchars`, use your DB's escape method (eg. `mysql_real_escape_string`).

Comment: @Rocket Even better, use PDO with prepared statements instead of manually escaping the db input. The PHP core dev team would really like to do away with the outdated mysql/mysqli extensions but they can't because so many people insist on continuing to use them. **To everyone:** Please do your part to encourage the use of prepared statements over manual escaping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not encode HTML-Specialchars when inserting into database, that way data is manipulated (and maybe different when editing the dataset). You should rather encode them when displaying it.

But yes, `htmlspecialchars()` is enough to prevent XSS as long as you don't forget to use it. The way YOU use it however is as secure as before. XSS is prevented through the encoded version, the database does not care about it.

Comment: You're right with almost everything you say but look closely at the OP's code - the way he is using `htmlspecialchars()`, it does *not* prevent XSS

Comment: Whether or not using htmlspecialchars works depends on the context. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

No, XSS is independent of the database. To avoid SQL-injection, you want to escape using something like mysql_real_escape_string or use prepared statements, but to avoid XSS you need to escape when outputting to HTML.

And there are a couple of gotchas there as well. Take a look at the [OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). It explains how to escape for different context.

htmlspecialchars/htmlentities will protect you if you are outputting untrusted data between tags, but will not protect you if you are outputting it in say a javascript event handler like this:

```
&lt;button onclick="confirm('do you want to delete &lt;?php echo htmlspecialhars($untrusted_data) ?&gt;')"&gt;
```

This is because you are escaping for HTML and not javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Nope - you're filtering the data before putting it into the database (which is unnecessary), but cancelling out the filter when outputting the data.

Store the data in the database unfiltered, and escape it when outputting:

```
 echo htmlspecialchars($unfiltered_data_from_database);
```

Comment: Make sure to `mysql_real_escape_string` before putting in the DB.

Comment: @Pekka , but i need to use the tags , this way i will lose the tags , i have done nothing !.

Comment: @wfareed You know: Preventing XSS is about encoding the tags? You'll need something like markdown or BBCodes as well.