# newline in Leaflet marker popup text

Tags: php, leaflet, newline

I have a form to associate some text to a marker on a Leaflet map:

```
<form action="map.php" method="POST">
 <section>
  <label>write some text here</label>
   <textarea id="text" rows="3" name="area"></textarea>
 </section>

 <input type="submit" value="show map" />
</form>
```

As you can see above, the content of the textarea is passed to the page map.php, where a map is shown.
On the map, the place marker is shown, and a popup contains the text posted through the textarea (variable `$text`):

```
<?php
$text = htmlspecialchars($_POST["text"]);
?>

<center>
 <div id="map" class="embed-container"></div>
</center>

<script>
  var map = L.map('map').setView([46.13, 11.11], 9);
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
      maxZoom: 17,
      minZoom: 9
    }).addTo(map);
</script>
<script>
  var icon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'img/gps.png',
        iconSize: [25, 25],
        });
  var marker = L.marker(['<?=$latitude;?>', '<?=$longitude;?>'], {icon: icon}).addTo(map);
  marker.bindPopup('<?=$text;?>');
</script>
```

The problem is that if I press **ENTER** while I write something in the textarea, nothing is passed to the popup marker.
I tried with **\n** and such, but nothing works. They are shown in the popup text as strings, not as newlines.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to use `<br>`

Comment: I have tried that too. It is shown as it is, as a string.

Comment: Possibly something can be done **within the java script**, to process the PHP variable `$text`. I do not know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The problem is that if I press **ENTER** while I write something in the textarea, nothing is passed to the popup marker.

This is inaccurate. The HTML inside the popup is receiving a newline character.

The problem is that the newline character is being displayed as collapsed whitespace. This is the default in HTML. Let me quote the [documentation for the `white-space` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space), inherited by default by all HTML elements:

> normal
>
> - Sequences of whitespace are collapsed. Newline characters in the source are handled as other whitespace. Breaks lines as necessary to fill line boxes.

HTML collapses whitespace characters, including tabs and line breaks (but excluding `&nbsp;`s).

[image: HTML and whitespace]

Text inside Leaflet popups simply follow the same rule. **Replace your newlines with [HTML `<br>` line breaks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)**, or otherwise wrap every line in a [block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) like a `<div>`.

[image: Popups and newlines]

If you are using [php](/questions/tagged/php), the easiest way is to use the [`nl2br` function](https://secure.php.net/nl2br). This is not necessarily the best way, as it is **very** prone to allowing XSS attacks in the hands of inexperienced developers. [Using `htmlspecialchars`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932431/prevent-xss-attacks) will not help if you are outputting JavaScript strings, enclosed in quotes. For these cases I recommend using [`json_encode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to provide the quotes and the quote scaping, i.e. `var foo = <?= json_encode(nl2br(str)); ?>;`

Comment: Yes. The function `nl2br` is what I was looking for. Brilliant reply.

Answer (score 2):

Was having a problem with nl2br() not working and the json_encode(nl2br(str)) worked, but it added double quotes ("str") to the beginning and end of the string. I was finally able to get it to work with the following code:

```
$string = str_replace("\r","",$string); 
$stringArray = explode("\n", $string);   
$string = implode("<br>", $stringArray);
```

I tried nl2br() after removinb "\r", and it still did not work, just broke it...

```
$string = str_replace("\r","",$string);
$string = nl2br($string); // DID NOT WORK!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<br>` in between your string.

**For example**:

```
var circle=L.circle([10.00, 77.77], {
    color:"Blue"
    fillOpacity:0.2
    radius:20000
}).addTo(map).bindTooltip("This is circle < br > blue colour")
```